# how to convert unicode (&#2970;) into a tamil character using java

Tags: java, unicode, tamil

i need to convert the below unicode to tamil character using java

```
 <html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
 <br>
#2970;&#3007;&#2969;&#3021;&#2965;&#2986;&#3021;&#2986;&#3010;&#2992;&#3021;<br>HEAVY 
DRIVER (HTV Licence)<br>Salary $ 900 +OT<br>Qualification 10, +2, ANY 
DEGREE<br>Age 25 to 40<br>Accommodation Free<br>Food Free<br>LASHING 
WORKER (HELPER)<br>Salary $ 900 + OT<br>Qualification 10, +2, ANY DEGREE<br>Age 
21 to 30<br>&#2984;&#3015;&#2992;&#3021;&#2990;&#3009;&#2965;&#2980;&#3021;&#2980;&#3015;&#2992;&#3021;&#2997;&#3009; &#2970;&#3014;&#2985;&#3021;&#2985;&#3016;&#2991;&#3007;&#2994;&#3021; : &#2972;&#2985;&#2997;&#2992;&#3007; 3, 4<br>Singapore 
Return Candidate not eligible<br>: &#2949;&#2979;&#3009;&#2965;&#2997;&#3009;&#2990;&#3021; :<br>&#2980;&#2990;&#3021;&#2986;&#3009;.&#2990;&#2985;&#3019;&#2965;&#2992;&#2985;&#3021; 
B.E.,<br>&#2980;&#2990;&#3021;&#2986;&#3009;&#2992;&#3006;&#2972;&#3021; &#2999;&#3009; &#2990;&#3006;&#2992;&#3021;&#2975;&#3021;<br>98A, 
&#2986;&#2996;&#3016;&#2991; &#2986;&#3015;&#2992;&#3009;&#2984;&#3021;&#2980;&#3009; &#2984;&#3007;&#2994;&#3016;&#2991;&#2990;&#3021;,<br>&#2965;&#3006;&#2997;&#2994;&#3021; 
&#2984;&#3007;&#2994;&#3016;&#2991;&#2990;&#3021; &#2958;&#2980;&#3007;&#2992;&#3007;&#2994;&#3021;, &#2986;&#2975;&#3021;&#2975;&#3009;&#2965;&#3021;&#2965;&#3019;&#2975;&#3021;&#2975;&#3016; - 614 601.<br>
</body>
```

I need the output to be like this

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<br>
சிங்கப்பூர்<br>HEAVY 
DRIVER (HTV Licence)<br>Salary $ 900 +OT<br>Qualification 10, +2, ANY 
DEGREE<br>Age 25 to 40<br>Accommodation Free<br>Food Free<br>LASHING 
WORKER (HELPER)<br>Salary $ 900 + OT<br>Qualification 10, +2, ANY DEGREE<br>Age 
21 to 30<br>நேர்முகத்தேர்வு சென்னையில் : ஜனவரி 3, 4<br>Singapore 
Return Candidate not eligible<br>: அணுகவும் :<br>தம்பு.மனோகரன் 
B.E.,<br>தம்புராஜ் ஷு மார்ட்<br>98A, 
பழைய பேருந்து நிலையம்,<br>காவல் 
நிலையம் எதிரில், பட்டுக்கோட்டை - 614 601.<br>
```

Comment: Why do you need to do this? A browser will treat the two forms exactly the same, and will render the Tamil characters properly from the character references.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `\u` escape character, which stands for unicode:

```
String tamil = "This is Tamil: \u0b9a\u0bcd\u0b99\u0bcd" 
             + "\u0b95\u0baa\u0bcd......"
```

Now, note; I converted your values to hexadecimal, as this is required instead of base-10.

Comment: Is it possible to get that hexadecimal text into tamil character

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. All I did is used a calculator with hexadecimal support, and copied your numbers and pasted the answer.

Comment: BTW, the `Integer` class contains a method `toHexString(int)` that would really help you.